# CSS, possible to move div on submenu?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

So i have this dropdown menu. What i was wondering is if it is possible to move the `txt` div when someone  hovers on a menu item that has a submenu. So that the submenu is not displaying over the textdiv. Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/6koazkhs/. So what i like is the `txt` div to float down when someone hovers the submenu, but not in a way that the `nav` div is stretching (color-wise). Here an image to explain what i want: [image]
Is such a thing possible?

Here my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>test</title>
<style>
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 20px 50px 150px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #E3CAA1;
}

ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
ul li ul li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
}
ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
div.txt{background:#ddd; width:100%}
div.nav{background:#ccc; width:100%; border-radius:10px;}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div class="nav"><ul><li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>
    Portfolio
    <ul>
      <li>Web Design</li>
      <li>Web Development</li>
      <li>Illustrations</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Blog</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul></div>
<div class="txt">Here my test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not possible with CSS as I know of. Have you considered using a JS-based solution?

Comment: Hi, yes.. but that toggles my txtdiv.. thats something i try to avoid.

Comment: But the dropdown menu *is* a toggle element based on your fiddle. What other ways can you achieve a binary state that does not involve toggling?

Comment: Ah, correct.. It is a simplified example of my code. In my code the submenu is not only shown when hover but also when active. However i'd like the submenu to float out of the parent ul but (i guess i have to do that with position:absolute; ?) but with a margin to the textdiv below.

Comment: Is there a class for the "open" state of the submenu? Would be useful so we can use JS to sniff out if a submenu is already open on a page and perform the offset accordingly.

Comment: Yes there is, so i do need jquery? Ok thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure if you have option to add extra div, but if you do this might help

```js
$(".Drop").hover(function(){
    $("#Space").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 20px 50px 150px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #E3CAA1;
}

ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
ul li ul li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
}
ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
div.txt{background:#ddd; width:100%}
div.nav{background:#ccc; width:100%; border-radius:10px;}

#Space{
     height:170px;
     display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav"><ul><li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li class="Drop">
    Portfolio
    <ul>
      <li>Web Design</li>
      <li>Web Development</li>
      <li>Illustrations</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Blog</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul></div>
<div id="Space"></div>
<div class="txt">Here my test</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but not quite what id like.. Thanks though.